# Using a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I'm trying to load a form with different information depending on which component of my listbox I double click. If I get which box was clicked(box 1, box2, etc.), that would be enough.

I've tried using the Doubleclick event, but it returns an object, and I'm not quite sure what to do with this object to get what I need.

Heres my code right now:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (Program.Customers.Count) - 1; i++)
            {
                if (Program.Customers[i].Name == searchTerm)
                {
                    SearchIndex.Add(i);   
                    listBox1.Items.Add(((Program.Customers[i].ID + " - " + Program.Customers[i].Name)));
                }
            }
            listBox1.Show();
```

What would be the best way to get which box was clicked? I need the ID, but I can get that with box was clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: Try casting the sender: `ListBox listBox = sender As ListBox;`.

Comment: Im really new to C#, so I'm not too sure what to do with this code. It doesn't compile in my doubleclick method. Could you explain what this does, or show where/how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you posted enough code to understand the problem.  The signature method for a double click event for a ListBox should look like this: `void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, you can directly compare the `sender` argument with your `ListBox` control instances, for example:

```
if (sender == listBox1)
{
    // ...
}
```

To get more information out of `sender` you need to cast it to something more specific first. So if you know your double click handler was only attached to list boxes, you can do

```
var listbox = (ListBox)sender;
```

and then access any of the properties of `ListBox` (such as [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx), which I mention because it's there specifically for your custom needs).